# Distortions when drawing using Wacom tablet in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, drawing-tablet

How do I prevent those distortions appearing when I draw?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Draw larger. Zoom out. You're drawing too small.

Or reduce the amount of "variation" on your brush.

When using a brush with pressure settings, if you have angles or curves too close together the pressure can cause "plugging". The easiest solution is to merely draw at a larger scale.